Git-TFS does not initialize a parent branch in the middle
I've almost imported all the repos, but I've an issue with one of the most important I need to import.
git command time: [00:01:37.0192709] gc
warning: Some Tfs branches could not have been initialized:

$/ProjectAB/Releases/2.2
$/Project2/ProjectXXX/DEV
$/ProjectAB/Releases/2.3.0.6
$/ProjectAB/Releases/2.3.0.8
$/ProjectAB/Releases/2.3.1.0
$/ProjectAB/Releases/2.3.1.3
$/ProjectAB/Releases/2.3
$/ProjectAB/Releases/2.4.0.20
$/ProjectAB/Releases/2.4.0.54
$/ProjectAB/Releases/2.5.0.62

Please report this case to the git-tfs developers! (report here : https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues/461 )
The /DEV inherits from a /Main and it has a lot of nested repos
The suspect I've is that this TFS folder

That starts with DEV and also I've a branch that's called DEV

And when on my local Git repo I try to do git branch DEV I got

fatal: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/DEV': 'refs/heads/DEV/BUG_xxxx'
exists; cannot create 'refs/heads/DEV

refs/heads/DEV/BUG_xxxx is the first one you see in the first picture
Any suggestion? I cannot rename actually the TFS folder or /DEV since it's used.

Not sure you reproduced the exact git-tfs use case with your git command but it if git-tfs try to create a DEV local branch and you already have a DEV/something, yes, you can't: it's a git limitation because it is materialized by trying to create file DEV whereas a directory DEV already exists.
You could try to give a different local name using the command:
git tfs branch --init $/Repository/path/DEV DEV/DEV


Hello @philpe, the issue is that I start retrieving all the repo with --branches=all so I don't do manually anything... but can I add that branch manually?

I got warning : There is already a remote for this tfs branch. Branch ignored!

Can you post the content of the '.git/config' file. I'm pretty sure renaming the local branch and fetching could work. Or deleting the mapping for this tfvc remote and retry the command.

here's the pastebin: https://pastebin.com/0ZfkhyTj the pwd is N22wZRY8MG. After you find the possible issue I'll update the question putting relevant part

can you provide also the command run because I don't see a conflict with DEV. Double check that the repository path is not in this file already initialized (that's why you got the warning). You tried to initialize the wrong branch?

yes sure I run \git-tfs.eae branch --init  $/PROJECT2/PROJECTUnivers/DEV DEV/DEV

Indeed, this one is already initialized as "PROJECTUnivers/DEV". So it's probably not the "cannot lock" error the reason why git-tfs failed to initialize the branch. So I don't have enough information to help you more on your problem...

but I don't understand how it's cllent on my local since I don't see it. can this be related to the TFS DEV folder name?

if you don't see it, maybe git-tfs just created the values in the config file and failed. Backup the config lines somewhere and delete them. Then retry initializing it.

It seems to have worked that approach! Now I'm checking, thanks a lot!!

Hi @advapi, is the issue resolved by backing up the configuration lines, deleting them, and then retry initializing?

yes @MiaoTian-MSFT!
